# Как вывести результат работы for в текстовый файл?

Tags: python

Задача создать файл `output.txt`, и добавить в него результат работы `for` с новых строк.

```py
data = response.json()
for item in data['result']['list']:
    if item.get("Id"):
         print(item.get("Id"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

собираете в переменную в нужном виде и сохраняете в файл.

Если строки с переводом строки. Сначала собираю все в список, затем формирую строку и отправляю на запись в файл

```py
result = []

for item in data['result']['list']:
    if item.get("Id"):
        result.append(str(item.get("Id")))

result_str = "\n".join(result)

with open("output.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write(result_str)
```

Или так

```py
with open("output.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write("\n".join([str(item.get("Id")) for item in data['result']['list'] if item.get("Id")]))
```

Comment: первый вариант отработал с ошибкой     result.append(str(item.get("Id")))
NameError: name 'result' is not defined.

Comment: Второй вариант отработал как надо :)

Comment: @bauna28 если такая ошибка, то забыли определить переменную `result` до цикла. А так этот код эквивалентен логически.

Answer (score 4):

Можно так, например:

```
data = response.json()
file = open('output.txt', 'w')
for item in data['result']['list']:
    if item.get("Id"):
         file.write(f'{item.get("Id")}\n')
file.close()
```

Или так еще:

```
data = response.json()
with open('output.txt', 'w') as file:
    for item in data['result']['list']:
        if item.get("Id"):
             file.write(f'{item.get("Id")}\n')
```

Comment: Спасибо, первый вариант подошел.

Comment: @bauna28, а второй - лучше.

Answer (score 4):

Функция `print` может принимать файловый объект в качестве аргумента.

```py
data = response.json()

with open("output.txt", "w") as f:
    for item in data['result']['list']:
        if item.get("Id"):
             print(item.get("Id"), file=f)
```